# apache bench: connection times vs. Time per request

Tags: load-testing, apachebench

This is one of my tests:

```
ab -n 100 -c 100 https://4ybg04diid.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   0.237 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      51600 bytes
HTML transferred:       3300 bytes
Requests per second:    421.36 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       237.327 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       2.373 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          212.33 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        8   60  12.1     54      76
Processing:    23   52  12.6     52     100
Waiting:       22   51  12.6     52     100
Total:         71  112  17.1    110     166
```

it says `Time per request=237.327 [ms] (mean)`, but below when it sums up the connection times it says `Total 112 mean`. Why is time per request longer?

Answer (score 0):

`Total 112 mean` refers to the processing time of the server, and `Time per request=237.327 [ms] (mean)` refers to the time from the user sending a request to receiving a reply. `Total 112 mean` is less time for network transmission than `Time per request=237.327 [ms] (mean)`.